# Are the sentence-structure and syntactic-analysis tags synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

As of this writing, the [sentence-structure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structure) tag is on 808 questions and the [syntactic-analysis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntactic-analysis) tag is on 117 questions, with only 4 questions having both tags.

It seems me that those are both the same thing. Is there any reason to maintain them as separate tags, or should we make one the synonym of the other and if so, which should be the master?

Comment: I agree and would vote for the former as more popular one to become the master tag.

Comment: There's also just the plain syntax tag.

Answer (score 3):

It seems  to me that a question about the structure of noun phrases for example, would come under syntactic analysis, but not sentence structure. Therefore, if the consensus is that these two should be merged, *syntactic analysis* should be the main tag, and *sentence structure* the synonym. However, I'm not sure that we definitely need to merge these two tags.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [sentence-structure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structure) is easier for the layperson to understand, and therefore should be the master, and [syntactic-analysis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntactic-analysis) its synonym.

I'm not an expert in this language, and may not know if these two are exactly the same thing. I'm only assuming they are, based on the question.